# How to consistently access a file?

Tags: java, python, c, multiplatform

I'm looking for a way to select a file, and a time frame/or until a certain action is performed, and "use" or "read" the file for that amount of time. Just a way to keep other programs from accessing it. The quality assurance department as my company is in need of an application like this and I believe it's possible to make it but I'm not sure how to approach this. Possibly "read" the file over and over until the time is reach or an action is performed?

Any ideas?

Comment: Which programming language will be using? On what platforms will it be used?

Comment: It'll be used on Windows (7-8.1) and Mac OSX (10.7 - 10.9) As far as the language goes, I'm very flexible. It doesn't really matter.

Comment: Using/reading a file doesn't prevent anyone else from reading it (or even writing to it) on most Unix-like platforms. I'm not really sure I understand what you're trying to do. Why don't you just move the file to somewhere people don't have access when they shouldn't access it?

Comment: We have separate scenarios for when a file is being used, and not present. If the file cannot be read because of it being used by another application, action "a" could happen but if it's missing action "b" would happen. We're just trying to cover all the scenarios.

Comment: **If you do not have full control on creation, deletion of the file** there'll **always** be a race: You test negativly for the file's existance and while preparing to invoke method "a" the file appears. You lost. You test positvly for the file's existance and while preparing for method "b" the file disappears. You lost again. **Find a different approach to solve the QA dep/s issue.**

Answer (score 0):

For Java, the answer would be to use a [FileLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileLock.html), which maps to the native mechanism of the operating system.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux you can block your file access using system calls like [flock](http://linux.die.net/man/2/flock).

A rather low-tech alternative can be:

1. Read the file
2. Keep it in memory.
3. Delete the file.
4. Work with your memory copy.
5. Dump your memory copy file into a new file with the same name when you have finished.

This second method is limited by the file and your system memory sizes, besides you can loose your file if the system stops working before reaching step 5. It is just a silly alternative to system calls. I would prefer to use system API services such `flock`.

Comment: Python has a wrapper for that by the way: https://docs.python.org/2/library/fcntl.html#fcntl.flock